# ASP.NET MVC project structure with user interface for editing content

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm developing a small cms based on asp.net mvc. I'd like to have one user interface for all editing e.g like this http://www.example.com/dashboard/{controller}/{action}etc. What is the best practice for this kind of project structure?

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking here. Are you asking how to setup urls such as `/dashboard/{controller}/{action}`?

Comment: My question is how should I structure my project. Is Scotts suggestion the "right" way? http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/07/31/asp-net-mvc-v2-preview-1-released.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to follow the standard MVC project conventions. Of course you can write your app using different conventions but the point of conventions is that once you learn where things go it's really easy to add new things and it's really easy for others to "read" your project. I would go with the suggestions in Scott's blog.